# Change default Odoo message header

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to change the message "Odoo Warning" from default Odoo messages.
Where is that message defined?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a function named `show_warning` or 'show_error` from this js file

`web/static/src/js/framework/crash_manager.js`
and you can change `title` as per your requirement.
Hope it will help you.